# How can I propagate changes from confluence's postgres database upward into confluence?

Tags: postgresql, confluence

I realize that this is a horrible hack, but I really wanted the ability to edit my group's wiki on the command line, and the `confluence 4.0` `cli` did not work for me after many hours of struggling with it.

I used the `psql` command to connect to Confluence's postgres database directly, and observed that there is a table called `bodycontent`, which stores the content of wiki pages.

I experimentally changed a new wiki page (using the wiki editor) and verified that the `body` column of the `bodycontent` changes to match the new edit.

Next, I used `UPDATE TABLE` to change the `body` column for the same entry to some other value. However, I observe that the change is not reflected in the `Confluence` front end.
That is, it still contains the old content.

**Does anyone know how to force the change to propagate to the Confluence front end?**

Comment: It's probably because of caching inside Confluence. You are looking for a way to refresh the Confluence cache

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, It appears that you are right, because restarting the Confluence service seems to resolve the problem. However, I wonder if there is a way to force it without restarting the entire service, since doing so will flush the entire cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to flush the Content Bodies cache -- https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/nY0UCg

Confluence is likely to become very angry at you if you continue hacking it this way though :)